# 'Allow [app name] to make and manage phone calls' permission and READ_PHONE_STATE

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, android-manifest, android-permissions, android-6.0-marshmallow

I have a Unity app (v5.2.4) built for Android that is asking for permission to 'make and manage phone calls' on Android (v6.0.1). Does some research it seems that it might be related to the READ_PHONE_STATE.

So I stripped out the READ_PHONE_STATE permission after building the apk, repackaged it and the message no longer appeared.

I'm not 100% sure what is putting the READ_PHONE_STATE into the app, unity forums say that the READ_PHONE_STATE was taken out in unity v5.2.

The app also uses Urban airship and doing a grep for READ_PHONE_STATE showed an urban airship bin file.

```
$ grep "READ_PHONE_STATE" -Rl . 
./Submodules/ua-unity-plugin/build/intermediates/lint-cache/api-versions-6-23.0.1.bin
```

What I'd like to know is, what is putting the permission in the manifest?

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking!!

Answer (score 0):

you can use the manifest merger report if it was native android. Try this blog post: [Hey, Where Did These Permissions Come From?](https://commonsware.com/blog/2015/06/25/hey-where-did-these-permissions-come-from.html)

I know for a fact that Unity uses this permission for analytics purposes. I am using Urbanairship in my current unity android project and We don't recollect using this permission. But from the grep it surely looks like that its part of the intermediate manifest generated from UA library.